# Crystal Report ODBC connection only shows "Add command"

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, crystal-reports-2008

I'm supposed to set up a crystal report for something less than exciting. This is my first experience using Crystal Reports (and its been agony).

When I add an ODBC connection, I put in the password (confirmed it works elsewhere) and press all the "Next" there are, and then I end up with this this:

I also am able to use a direct query when I do "add command" and can access the database tables that way, but this is less than ideal.

[image: Crystal Report Standard Report Creation Wizard]

My understanding is that the tables from the database are supposed to be listed under my connection, but all I see is "add command"

Does this mean I am not connected to the Database?

How do I correct this?

Comment: When you are able to see the add command it means you were able to make connection to database. Check the below links that will be helpful: http://scn.sap.com/thread/1532836, http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=1004707

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the user you setup in the ODBC Data Source Administrator has access to those tables in the database.

Comment: i forgot about this question... years later and i have moved onto other problems. thanks, but i have no way of verifying anymore.